# Sorting a hash by the value and then part of the key in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I have a hash of names and ranks (keys) and a number (value) with the format:

```
"\nName\nSecondName\nRank: 12345/150000" => 100

"\nThirdName\nFourthName\nRank: 24567/150000" => 71

"\nFifthName\nSixthName\nRank: 10101/150000" => 71
```

and so on 150,000 times...

With Perl, I would like to sort the hash primarily by the value number, and then secondarily by the first number of the rank, to look like this:

```
"\nName\nSecondName\nRank: 12345/150000" => 100

"\nFifthName\nSixthName\nRank: 10101/150000" => 71

"\nThirdName\nFourthName\nRank: 24567/150000" => 71
```

Comment: You know you can't sort the hash itself. You mean to print it out (or something else) in that order?

Comment: @BSull yes, that is what I meant

Comment: Whatever your data is and whatever you're doing with it, I'm _sure_ there must be a more sensible way to store it than the format you show above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @ordered_keys =
    sort {
       $hash{$b} <=> $hash{$a}
    ||
       ($a =~ m{: ([0-9]+)/})[0] <=> ($b =~ m{(: [0-9]+)/})[0]
    }
    keys %hash;

for my $key (@ordered_keys) {
   my $val = $hash{$key};
   ...
}
```

Comment: does the `$a =~ m{: ([0-9]+)/}` in list context return an array of all matches?

Comment: @Cupidvogel, a list of all matches, yes. (Impossible to return an array.)

Comment: Then what happens to the parenthesised groups? How are they returned?

Comment: @Cupidvogel, uh, that's what I called matches, so let's be more specific: In list context, the match operator returns what each parenthesised group matched, or true if there aren't any. Slightly different when /g i used.

Comment: Suppose the pattern is something like `\d+([a-w]+)`. This pattern itself is present for say, 5 times in the string, like **I love 123 foo, also 3245baz as well as 410bar**. Then?

Comment: @ikegami Works perfectly, Thank you.  Only thing is I wanted the value sort in the opposite direction so I just swapped $a and $b.

Comment: @Cupidvogel, The whole pattern matches `410bar`, and it returns what the only capture matches: `bar`.

Comment: @ysth, Not sure, but I think ST would actually slow it down. It would get rid of some code duplication, though.

Comment: depends how much duplication of values there is...from the example, I'd guess a lot